# Logstash not able to connect secured (ssl) Elastic search cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have installed Logstash,elasticsearch and kibana in single instance and installed X-pack also for TLS communication. enabled ssl communication in elasticsearch and kibana working good but logstash unable to connect elasticsearch , but i can curl elasticsearch url https://localhost:9200 there is no firewall blocking also, 
I have generated open ssl certificate and key file  and kept in elasticsearch

```
input {
  beats {
     client_inactivity_timeout => 1000
     port => 5044
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => [ "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} zeppelin IDExtractionService transactionId %{WORD:transaction_id} operation %{WORD:otype} received request duration %{NUMBER:duration} exception %{WORD:error}" ]
  }
}
filter {
    if "beats_input_codec_plain_applied" in [tags] {
        mutate {
            remove_tag => ["beats_input_codec_plain_applied"]
        }
    }
}

filter {
    if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
        mutate {
            remove_tag => ["_grokparsefailure"]
        }
    }
}

xpack.monitoring.enabled: true
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.url: https://localhost:9200
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    user => elastic
    password => password
    manage_template => false
#    ssl_certificate_verification => false
    ssl => true
    cacert => '/etc/elasticsearch/ca/key.pem'
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"

  }
}
```

elastic search config file

```
cluster.name: my-application
network.host: 0.0.0.0
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.key:  /opt/elasticsearch/ca/ca.key
xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate: /opt/elasticsearch/ca/ca.crt
```

logstash log files

```
[2018-05-16T05:28:16,421][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@localhost:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@localhost:9200/][Manticore::ClientProtocolException] localhost:9200 failed to respond"}
[2018-05-16T05:28:17,201][WARN ][logstash.shutdownwatcher ] {"inflight_count"=>1, "stalling_thread_info"=>{"other"=>[{"thread_id"=>24, "name"=>nil, "current_call"=>"[...]/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/interval.rb:89:in `sleep'"}]}}
[2018-05-16T05:28:21,422][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@localhost:9200/, :path=>"/"}
[2018-05-16T05:28:21,422][INFO ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@localhost:9200/, :path=>"/"}
[2018-05-16T05:28:21,424][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@localhost:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@localhost:9200/][Manticore::ClientProtocolException] localhost:9200 failed to respond"}
[2018-05-16T05:28:21,425][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@localhost:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@localhost:9200/][Manticore::ClientProtocolException] localhost:9200 failed to respond"}
[2018-05-16T05:28:22,202][WARN ][logstash.shutdownwatcher ] {"inflight_count"=>1, "stalling_thread_info"=>{"other"=>[{"thread_id"=>24, "name"=>nil, "current_call"=>"[...]/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/interval.rb:89:in `sleep'"}]}}
[2018-05-16T05:28:26,425][INFO ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@localhost:9200/, :path=>"/"}
[2018-05-16T05:28:26,426][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@localhost:9200/, :path=>"/"}
[2018-05-16T05:28:26,427][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@localhost:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@localhost:9200/][Manticore::ClientProtocolException] localhost:9200 failed to respond"}
[2018-05-16T05:28:26,427][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@localhost:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@localhost:9200/][Manticore::ClientProtocolException] localhost:9200 failed to respond"}
[2018-05-16T05:28:27,201][WARN ][logstash.shutdownwatcher ] {"inflight_count"=>1, "stalling_thread_info"=>{"other"=>[{"thread_id"=>24, "name"=>nil, "current_call"=>"[...]/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/interval.rb:89:in `sleep'"}]}}
root@5c417caecc5f:/var/log/logstash#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable monitoring for elasticsearch in the logstash.yml configuration file.

**/etc/logstash/logstash.yml**

```
xpack.monitoring.enabled: true
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.url: http://X.X.X.X:9200
```

See this post for more information :

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-unreachable-error-in-logstash/75157/7

And the documentation (maybe needed for TLS/SSL monitoring settings) :

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.2/configuring-logstash.html#monitoring-settings

```
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.ssl.ca
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.ssl.truststore.path
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.ssl.truststore.password
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.ssl.keystore.path
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.ssl.keystore.password
```

If this doesn't work, can I see your **/etc/logstash/logstash.yml** configuration file ?

Comment: Hello crank, Thanks for reply, i have posted my logstash.yml above ,  still i am getting same error , can you check logs logstash is connecting  http over https  and i can see dead instance error also

Comment: I suppose that you have to set up configuration for xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.ssl.* too.

Is your configuration without TLS/SSL worked between logstash and elastisearch or you're trying to setup directly with secure connections ?

Comment: it s worked before without TLS, after updating ssl configuration getting problem